# Telerik grid rebind return additional parameter from controler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, telerik-grid

Hi all i need to pass parameter from controller to client and process it
controller:

```
public ActionResult GetTerminalList(string GroupID, string NodeLevel, string ItemsArr)
{
...
// how to pass my parameter AllChecked?
return View(new GridModel
            {
                Data = items               
            });
}
```

client code:

```
    var arr = new Array();
    var nodeLevel = GetCurrentNodeLevel(e.item,arr);
    var groupId =  GetGroupId();    

    var grid = $('#TreeTermGrid').data('tGrid');        
    grid.rebind({ GroupID: groupId, NodeLevel: nodeLevel, ItemsArr: arr});
and here get var AllChecked  = grid.GetParam("AllChecked"); // fake
```

Main problem to pass it parameter in one request or detect that all checkboxes in all pages are checked.
Help me please, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try create a subclass inheriting from GridModel to include the new property.  However, if I remember, this is for AJAX capabilities, so this would work differently as I don't know if you can embed additional parameters into the model this way.

A workaround for this could be to make a separate AJAX request to get this additional information...

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for response, i can subclass GridModel but i cant get how to get it from telerik grid....

Comment: Then it's probably not possible without calling your own separate method from the server as a separate AJAX request.